# How to prevent collection() from setting if the key already exist on firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've created a collection called "coins" these coins such as bitcoin are added to the database if the user clicks the follow button which appears next to each coin that is displayed on my site. The problem is that if the user clicks the follow button more than once, that coin will be added to the database every time the user clicks it. What I want to have done is if that specific coin is already in the database, do not set(). I'm sure there is a method for this but I am not sure. All the data I set() is coming from an object called data which holds all the data for the coin.

```
const FollowIcon = ({ price }) => {
  const db = firebase.firestore();

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("Follow");

  const [following, setFollowing] = useState(false);
```

this is the top of my functional component.
{ price } holds the unique coin data.
The reason it is unique is that I made the URL dynamic so if
the user visits bitcoin, the url will be PriceDetails/BTC

```
const handleClick = () => {
    let data = {
      following: following,
      logo_url: price.logo_url,
      id: price.id,
      name: price.name,
      price: price.price,
      userId: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    };
//adding the data above to firebase's real time database
    db.collection("coins")
      .doc()
      .set(data);


    setTitle("Following");
    setFollowing(!following);
 };
```

the handleClick function is what I pass into the Onclick on my followButton

I expect that if the user clicks the follow button multiple times, that coin will only be added one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `price.id` defines the ID that you want to be unique, you can use that id as the name of the documents in the `coins` collection:

```
db.collection("coins")
  .doc(price.id)
  .set(data);
```

Now the second time you run this, it simply updates the same document.